# Autofac resolve by interface's interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have one common empty interface (say IService).
And I have a lot of interfaces which derive from IService and used by implementations later, e.g.:

```
interface IUserService : IService { }
class UserService : IUserService
```

What I tried is that

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IService))))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

but it's working only if I derive IService on implementation directly, but I have one more specific interface (IUserService for example).
I need to register types for each interface-implementation(IUserService-UserService with IService). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

Your code as is will "just work". This is because `UserService` implements `IService`, which meets the `Any` check. And `AsImplementedInterfaces` ensures that `UserService` is registered against both `IService` **and** `IUserService`.

So if you inject in `IUserService` as a dependency then `UserService` should be resolved.

## Extra stuff to consider:

One thing you could improve (although it won't do anything other than speeding up your code sample and making it clearer) is tweak your call to:

```
i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IService))
```

That part of the code is likely not doing what you *think* it is doing.

I suspect what you want it to do is answer the question - does `i` inherit from or implement `IService`.

But it actually does it the other way around, it is asking whether `IService` inherits from or implements `i` (or even if `i` is `IService`). The only value of `i` that meets that condition is, unfortunately, `IService` itself.

To make this clearer this, swap the order:

```
var serviceType = typeof(IService);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => serviceType .IsAssignableFrom(i)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

*In the context of your code sample, your form of the code does in fact work (since we know that `IService` will be returned from `GetInterfaces`) - but it takes a bit of thinking to understand why it works. If you reverse them as shown, the code is slightly easier to understand.*

Comment: Yup, that is what I didn't understand, thanks for sorting this out for me